# Mystery line-break

Tags: css, line-breaks

Take a look here in the right-hand colum where it says 'Performance figures are net of fees':

http://www.securisinvestments.com/

For some reason the text is not filling the entire paragraph tag i.e. the word 'fees' looks like it has a br tag before it. I thought it might be something to do with `text-align: justify;` but I can't find any reference to that in the CSS.

Can anyone see what's going on? It's got me stumped...

Thanks

Osu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line above the date has a margin-bottom of 20px and is floated.

Remove this 20px.

```
.widget-title span {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's the one! Will mark this as the answer in 7 mins (when it lets me). Thanks @dave

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue with the `span` above:

```
.widget-title {overflow: hidden;}
.widget-title span {margin: 0;}
```

This solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<p class="small" style="white-space: nowrap;">* Performance figures are net of fees.</p>
```

Plus I've just noticed the bottom margin of the title above this is large thus stopping the small text stretching across.

If possible give `.widget-title span` `margin-bottom: 0px;`

Comment: same solution has already been mentioned twice. it's still a mere workaround